# First time users per day in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new to writing queries in Postgres and am interested in understanding how one can count the **number of unique first time users per day**.

If the table only has two columns- `user_id` and `start_time` which is a timestamp that indicates the time of use. If a user has used on previous day, the `user_id` should not be counted.

Why does the following query not work? Shouldn't it be possible to select distinct on two variables at once?

```
SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT min(start_time::date), user_id), 
       start_time::date as date 
FROM mytable 
GROUP BY date
```

produces

> ERROR:  function count(date, integer) does not exist

The output would look like this

```
        date count
1 2017-11-22    56
2 2017-11-23    73
3 2017-11-24    13
4 2017-11-25    91
5 2017-11-26   107
6 2017-11-27    33...
```

Any suggestions about how to count distinct min Date and user_id and then group by date in psql would be appreciated.

Comment: They way you are using Distinct and count is not permitted . You can do Select count(*) FROM (select user_id,min(start_time) from mytable group by trunc(start_time)) ,user_id

Comment: "Why does the following query not work?"- because `count` can work on only one argument. Moreover, your logic to count number of unique first time users per day in the query is not quite right. We need to keep track of users logged on any previous day to skip it from counting today. using `DISTINCT` won't help you achieve it.

Comment: This error message only hides the next problem: even if Postgres supported two columns to pass to the `count()` function, you can not nest aggregates functions - otherwise you could simply create a single column with an anonymous record as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49193321/330315

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
select start_time,count(*) as count from
(
   select user_id,min(start_time::date) as start_time
   from mytable
   group by user_id
)distinctRecords
group by start_time;
```

This will count each user only once for min date.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this logic:

- First find the first login time of each `user_id` -  `MIN` 
  `(start_time)` .
- Joining the above results with the main table, increment the count of
  user only if the user has not  logged in yet. `COUNT`  does not add 1 to the record when it's argument is `NULL`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b56d82/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable
    (user_id int, start_time varchar(19))
;

INSERT INTO yourtable
    (user_id, start_time)
VALUES
    (1, '2018-03-19 08:05:01'),
    (2, '2018-03-19 08:05:01'),
    (1, '2018-03-19 08:05:04'),
    (3, '2018-03-19 08:05:01'),
    (1, '2018-03-20 08:05:04'),
    (2, '2018-03-20 08:05:04'),
    (4, '2018-03-20 08:05:04'),
    (3, '2018-03-20 08:05:06'),
    (3, '2018-03-20 08:05:04'),
    (3, '2018-03-20 08:05:05'),
    (1, '2018-03-21 08:05:06'),
    (3, '2018-03-21 08:05:05'),
    (6, '2018-03-21 08:05:06'),
    (3, '2018-03-22 08:05:05'),
    (4, '2018-03-22 08:05:05'),
    (5, '2018-03-23 08:05:05')

;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH f
     AS (  SELECT user_id, MIN (start_time) first_start_time
             FROM yourtable
         GROUP BY user_id)
SELECT t.start_time::DATE
    ,count( CASE WHEN  t.start_time > f.first_start_time
                    THEN NULL ELSE 1 END )
FROM yourtable t JOIN f ON t.user_id = f.user_id
GROUP BY start_time::DATE
ORDER BY 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b56d82/1/0)**:

```
| start_time | count |
|------------|-------|
| 2018-03-19 |     3 |
| 2018-03-20 |     1 |
| 2018-03-21 |     1 |
| 2018-03-22 |     0 |
| 2018-03-23 |     1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use following query:

```
select count(user_id ) total_user , start_time 
from   (
  SELECT min (date (start_time)) start_time, user_id        
  FROM mytable )tmp 
group by start_time
```

Comment: This won't return the counts

Comment: you can use fallowing query ..
select count(user_id ) total_user , start_time from   (SELECT min (date (start_time))start_time, user_id        
FROM mytable )tmp group by start_time