# How do I get Active Record query that works in Rails console working in a rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rake, rake-task

I have an active record query that works fine in the console but does not work when I use it in a rake task

Here is the beginning of my rake task:

```
namespace :attendees do
  desc "Migrate sms plans to receive_sms attribute for attendees"
  task migrate_sms_plans: :environment do
    attendees_with_sms_plans = Attendee.select('attendees.id, attendees.phone, attendees.local_phone').joins(:plans).where('plans.name = ?', "Yes! SMS!")
```

Why does the select statement works in my rails console but give me the following error when I use it in the rake task, and how do I fix it:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function count(integer, character varying, character varying) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(attendees.id, attendees.phone, attendees.local_...
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Turned out the error was not the select statement, but in the next line:

```
puts <<-TEXT
    Going to migrate #{attendees_with_sms_plans.count} attendees from "Yes! SMS!" plan to receive_sms: true attribute on Attendee Model
TEXT
```

which I fixed by changing to:

```
puts <<-TEXT
    Going to migrate #{attendees_with_sms_plans.to_a.count} attendees from "Yes! SMS!" plan to receive_sms: true attribute on Attendee Model
TEXT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so far as guessed the error: -

```
attendees_with_sms_plans = Attendee.select('attendees.id, attendees.phone, attendees.local_phone').joins(:plans).where('plans.name = ?', "Yes! SMS!")
```

`attendees_with_sms_plans` will results as `Attendee::ActiveRecord_Relation`

and on calling `attendees_with_sms_plans.count` will results into

> ERROR:  function count(integer, character varying, character varying)
>   does not exist

which means that [Postgres does not support count()with more than one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49193321/sqlexceptionhelper-error-function-countcharacter-varying-integer-does-not)

So the solution is you can use `size()` instead if `count()` like so: -

```
attendees_with_sms_plans.size
```

Comment: Good guess! Apparently this behaviour is also documented: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count

Comment: Turned out the error was not the select statement, but in the next line: ```    puts <<-TEXT
    Going to migrate #{attendees_with_sms_plans.count} attendees from "Yes! SMS!" plan to receive_sms: true attribute on Attendee Model
    TEXT```

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether function count is exists or not with below query

```
SELECT n.nspname
FROM pg_extension e
   JOIN pg_namespace n
      ON e.extnamespace = n.oid
WHERE e.extname = 'count';
```

If that not on your `search_path`, your query will not find the function.

To have the extension in a different schema, in the following example public, drop and recreate it:

```
DROP EXTENSION count;
CREATE EXTENSION count SCHEMA public;
```